# error in data not found when trying to make prediction

Tags: r, prediction

Question is: What is the predicted number of repetitions for individuals with arm lengths of 30 in.? Discuss the adequacy of a linear approximation.

But I have issues when trying to predict the data. BenchPress cannot be found.

```
combine <- read.csv("C:/Users/Yuxi Liu/Desktop/nfl_combine2017.csv")
cols <- c("ArmLength", "BenchPress")
x <- combine$ArmLength 
y <- combine$BenchPress

combine_model = lm(ArmLength ~ BenchPress, data = combine)
confint(combine_model, conf.level=0.95)
summary((combine_model)$coefficients)

plot(ArmLength~ BenchPress, data = combine,
     xlab = "Arm Length",
     ylab = "Bench Press",
     main = "Arm Length vs Bench Press",
     pch = 10,
     cex = 1,
     col = "grey")
abline(lm(combine_model))

combine_model = lm(ArmLength ~ BenchPress, data = combine)
new.combine <- data.frame(x=c(30))
predict(combine_model, new.combine, se.fit = TRUE)
```

Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'BenchPress' not found

Comment: The `newdata` object has to contain variables whose names match those used in the model. Change `new.combine <- data.frame(x=c(30))` to `new.combine <- data.frame(BenchPress = 30)`

Comment: On second look, are you sure you don't have your `x` and `y` variables mixed up in your `lm` model?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but according to the question, it should be ArmLength = 30, because I need to make predictions when ArmLength is equal to 30

Comment: Right, which is why I asked about you mixing up your variables

Comment: Oh, I see my issues. Thanks